# C++ / JNI - How to access enum declared in .h in JAVA (Android NDK)

Tags: java, c++, enums, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I have header file in C++ in which is declared some enum.

```
// enum.h
enum event {
    event_1,
    event_2,
    event_3,
    event_4
}
```

C++ files and header are compiled (with GNU) in library .so.

Now I want to do in my Java class like that :

```
// Test.java
public class Test {
    private event currentEvent;

    public test() {
        if (currentEvent == event.event_1)
            ; // I will do my stuff
    }
}
```

Anyone has suggestions ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I doubt there is a direct way of doing this.

For C or C++, you can use [SWIG](http://www.swig.org/Doc1.3/Java.html#simple_enums).  It automatically generates Java wrappers for C++ classes and elements.

> 21.3.5.5 Simple enums
>
> This approach is similar to the type unsafe approach. Each enum item
>   is also wrapped as a static final integer. However, these integers are
>   not generated into a class named after the C/C++ enum. Instead, global
>   enums are generated into the constants interface. Also, enums defined
>   in a C++ class have their enum items generated directly into the Java
>   proxy class rather than an inner class within the Java proxy class. In
>   fact, this approach is effectively wrapping the enums as if they were
>   anonymous enums and the resulting code is as per anonymous enums. The
>   implementation is in the "enumsimple.swg" file.
>
> Compatibility Note: SWIG-1.3.21 and earlier versions wrapped all enums
>   using this approach. The type unsafe approach is preferable to this
>   one and this simple approach is only included for backwards
>   compatibility with these earlier versions of SWIG.